# MySQLi PHP using OR and AND

Tags: mysql

Sorry about the title, I wasn't sure how to word it

I'm wanting to make a instant messaging system with PHP (I've done ajax for it) but I'm not sure how to get the query, I'm wanting something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user='$to' AND sender='$username' OR user='$username' AND sender='$to'"
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? Or a mysqli_fetch_array for two invididual queries on the same variable.

Comment: Did you try? What/where is the problem?

Comment: You'll need to group them with parenthesis.

Comment: You should use parameters for your queries, ranging that munging query strings with parameter values that can cause syntax errors.

Comment: That looks like it's dangerously full of [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com). Try to use placeholder values whenever possible.

Comment: @tadman That wasn't the real code, just a modified query. Any variable goes through htmlentities

Comment: **No!** `htmlentities` is *strictly* for HTML escaping, it is not suitable for SQL. Use **placeholder values**, please, for your own safety. Doing anything else is not only way more code, but it's asking for trouble.

Comment: @PhilGibson that's hilarious. Do you *really* think that a function called "**HTML** entities" has whatever relation to **SQL**?

Comment: @YourCommonSense The code get's a post value, for instance: $post = htmlentities($_POST['post']), and with $post that submits into the database,

Comment: I quite understands what the code is. The question is, does it make any sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parenthesis to use multiple operations to work as single operation in query. This is the typical approach anyway, and very useful for using multiple AND, OR operators in a query.

For you case, query should be like

```
"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ( user='$to' AND sender='$username' ) OR ( user='$username' AND sender='$to' )"
```

Notice that tho we used 4 conditions, but with parenthesis we shrieked it into 2 separate conditions and ultimately one OR operation in the query.

Some good reading about this stuff at [this article](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and_or.php) in case you want to dig it more